# Why does this type-problematic Swift code not generate an error?

Tags: swift

Consider the following code:

```
func f(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let x = dict["mykey"]?.integerValue
    // Do something with x
}
```

There is no indication of what type `dict["mike"]` could be, yet I can invoke `integerValue` on it. How does this code not cause an error, or at least a warning?

Comment: Explained in my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECsuppressing

Comment: @matt Thanks for that link!

Comment: @matt: so we try to call `integerValue` property on the instance of `AnyObject`, but it might not necessarily exist for e.g. a custom class type used as value for some key in the dictionary?

Comment: @dfri Try it yourself: `class Dog{}; let d:AnyObject = Dog(); d.integerValue`

Comment: @matt Thanks matt. I did actually try this in my own answer, but I'm wondering _what_  causes the `nil` return: 1. is an actual `.integerValue` property called for `AnyObject` instance containing an instance of our `Dog` type, thereafter failing to do anything with the `Dog` value hence returning `nil`, or 2. no `.integerValue` property exists for `Dog`, so trying to find such a property yields `nil`?

Comment: Right, read the explanation in my online book. There is no `integerValue` property, so Swift safely returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

This does not cause an error or warning because `AnyObject` allows any NSObject method to be called on it the equivalent of `id` in Objective-C. So in this case the compiler does not know what it will be there and if the object does not support `integerValue` then you will get 0 back at the end of it based on testing in the playground.

Comment: Yep it will be 0 by the looks of it in the playground, missed the optional chain there.

Comment: I see. If `AnyObject` is used, then all type-safety bets are off.

Comment: Yes then you can do the casting using `guard / if let as?` to check the type or `is` but you can call virtually any method on an `AnyObject`

Answer (score 0):

The return from `.integerValue` is an optional `Int`: `let x: Int?`. The property `integerValue` will initialize an integer using the value for key `"myKey"`; if it fails, however, if will return `nil`.

If the `AnyObject` *value* for a certain key in your dictionary contain no successful method to initialize an integer given the value (i.e., by `integerValue` computed property), then the last step *after* the optional chaining on `x` in your question above will return nil, e.g.:

```
class MyClass {
    var myInt : Int
    init() {
        myInt = 1
    }
}

var myDict : [String:AnyObject] = ["myKey":MyClass()]
let a = myDict["myKey"]               // MyClass, OK
let x = myDict["myKey"]!.integerValue // nil
```

*Hence*, note that it's not the actual lookup for key `"myKey"` that returns nil above, but the attempted call to property `.integerValue` on an `AnyObject` instance of a `MyClass()` object, from which it, naturally, doesn't exist any (for the compiler) know way to construct an `Int` from.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` Optional-unwrapping is a red herring. It would be better to write the example like this:

```
func f(dict: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let x = dict["mykey"]!.integerValue
}
```

Or even better, like this:

```
let ao : AnyObject = "howdy"
ao.integerValue
```

As long is something is typed as an AnyObject, any known class message can be sent to it. Swift will deal safely with the result. Thus, for example:

```
class Dog{}
let d:AnyObject = Dog()
d.integerValue // nil, because a Dog has no integerValue property
```